# На много ли — это правильно?

Tags: предлоги, слитно-раздельно, приставка

Правильно ли выбрана форма написания ***НА*** в приведенных примерах? Корректно ли они составлены?

(1) ***Он намного её старше.***  (2) ***А на много ли он старше?***

(3) ***Он тогда намного опоздал.*** (4) ***А на много ли он опоздал?***

**Имеющаяся информация:**

Орфографический словарь: намного, нареч. (***намного лучше***), но числит. на много (***на много лет***)

Большой толковый словарь: НАМНОГО, нареч. (**обычно** при сравнит. ст.). В значительной степени, значительно. Стать н. сильнее. Н. улучшить качество продукции. Сегодня н. теплее, чем было вчера.

**Соответственно, возникают вопросы:**

Форма ***на много ли*** здесь не рассматривается, возможно ли раздельное написание предлога НА?

В текстах встречается сочетание ***намного превосходить/ превышать,*** но можно ли сказать ***опоздать намного?***

Пример:

Он даже сказал вслух: « Грустно!» ― и посмотрел при этом на часы ― **на много ли он опоздал.** [Владимир Дудинцев. Не хлебом единым (1956)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раздельное написание *возможно*, если подразумеваются единицы измерения (**сколько** их; на много ли = **на какую величину**, речь не идет о сравнении "по бартеру"). Приведенные проблемные примеры (книжный - в меньшей степени) лишь *стилистически* проблематичны, но формально им есть оправдание: в вопросах ожидается ответ в "штуках лет/количестве времени" - "неудачность" заключается в отбрасывании слова "лет" и " (сколько) времени/часов/минут - по часам". Со словом "долго" такой дилеммы нет (слитно) - "долгота" не имеет *прямой* единицы измерения, с таковыми единицами она связана через понятие "время". Менее проблемный пример (единицы измерения понятны):

> Он достал последний графин текилы и, окинув взглядом двенацдать рюмок,
>   засомневался: **на много ли** [*рюмок* или тостов] хватит.

В выражениях "намного позже" и "намного опоздал (без разглядывания часов или иного проясняющео контекста)" заложено *сравнение* с установленным сроком (=сильно ли опоздал), а не указание величин ("на сколько" не подразумевается), поэтому оснований для раздельного написания не видно.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за  ответ.  Приведенные предложения – это наша обычная речь с обычной грамматикой , там ничего «не отброшено»,  а  коммуникативная ситуация вполне ясная. И ясно просматриваются два значения:  утвердительная оценка (намного) и вопрос (на много, на много ли).  Если вас просят «посмотри, мы на мнОго опаздываем?»,  то что вы  ответите?  Посмотрите на часы и скажете: «да, намного»?

Comment: Но это неестественный ответ, потому что намного – это качественная оценка, а вашего собеседника интересует  оценка количественная, и в данном случае «намного» обозначает «на сколько».  Так что, раздельно напишем? Вы согласны, что существуют две формы письма? Но вот только в словаре раздельная форма "на  много" без  указания единиц измерения не приводится.

Comment: Для _(на)много_ - да, две формы, в зависимости от того, ожидается ли ответ в количестве времени. Время - измеряемая величина, в отличие от "долгости" (там с большим перевесом "побеждает" слитность).

Comment: Спасибо, меня как раз это интересовало. А вы, кажется, уже заранее защищаете слитное "надолго", к которому у меня еще остались вопросы